# How to play sound effects on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a game that plays sounds when some events occur.

Currently, I am using `AVAudioPlayer` for the purpose of playing the sound. But just the bare `AVAudioPlayer` has a noticeable lag time before the first playback and it stops music played by other apps.

Also, it stops the ongoing playback when a new playback is ordered. Surely, I could use a list of `AVAudioPlayer`s for each of the effects, but that feels clunky.

[image: Sound stops when other sound is played]

I want something that will play effects mixed, one on top of another; and I want them to be played on top of background music, if there is any. I do not use any sorts of frameworks, like `SpriteKit` or Unity. So, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Settled to a queue of AVAudioPlayers for each sound effect.

Not pausing music achieved with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29027722

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your `AVAudioSession` to `Category` rather than the default (`Solo`).

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];` should do the trick.

If this doesn't work for you, the [AVAudioSession documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories) has a lot of information on Audio Session Categories, Modes, etc.